# Cannot change lock screen other than password/PIN after installing certificate

Tags: lock-screens, certificates

I am using **XOLO Q1010i**. In order to use the university WiFi network, I need to install an authority certificate (WiFi credential). To do so, the device made me installing a lock screen (PIN or Password), any other lock screen choice is not available and grayed with a message

> Disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage

Is it possible use lock screen other than those?

Comment: Talk to the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a restriction enforced by Android: when the user has installed their own certificates, a secure lock screen is required. Without rooting, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Android imposed this restriction for "security" purposes. When whoever buys the android uses their own certificates, a secure lock screen is required. You can root it. But that's about it. You should talk to administration or even an I.T. student.